# React state updating but not rendering on child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I know the state is updating because 1. the 'Loading...' is going away, I can console log this.state.images to see the array. However when the state updates and the loading goes the searchbar shows up but the Card's within CardList do not.

They do show up when I search for a correct string, but not before.

If I pass this.state.images to CardList they show up perfectly. However when I move to the filteredImages they only show up when filtered.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      images:[],
      searchfield: ''
    }
  }

  getLabels = (image) => {
    const AuthKey = key.key;
    const res = axios.post(`https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=${AuthKey}`, {
      requests: [
        {
          image:{
            source:{
              imageUri: `http://storage.googleapis.com/${image}`
            }
          },
          features:[
            {
              type:"LABEL_DETECTION",
              maxResults:10
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    });

    res.then(function (response) {
      const results = response.data.responses[0].labelAnnotations;
      const ex = results.map(result => {
        return result.description;
      }); 
      return ex;
    });

    return res;

  };

  componentDidMount() {
      imageFiles.imageFiles.forEach(img => {
        this.getLabels(img).then(result => {
          const results = result.data.responses[0].labelAnnotations;
          const labels = results.map(result => {
          return result.description;
        });
        //Add new values to the state 
        this.setState({images:[...this.state.images, {img, labels}]});
      });
    })
  }

  onSearchChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({searchfield: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    const filteredImages = this.state.images.filter(image => {
      return image.labels.includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase());
    });
    // Create an array of objects to store the image path and the labels detected from Google Vision
    if (this.state.images.length === 0) {
      return <h1>Loading...</h1>
    } else {
      return (
        <Grid className="App">
          <SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
          <CardList images={filteredImages} />
        </Grid>
      )}
  }

}

export default App;
```

Comment: What does your `labels` look like? Maybe you have to use `toLowerCase()` on those as well: `image.labels.some(label => label.toLowerCase() === this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase())`

Comment: @Tholle has pointed out correctly. I see that is the only mistake

Comment: add filteredImages in component state. and move you filter logic in onSearchChange function AND call setstate for filteredImages from there.
now whre you pass filtered images it should do what you want.
Let me know if you need complete answer.

Comment: @ManojYadav I tried but I think I've done something wrong. Could I get that more complete answer please?

Comment: The problem is that filteredImages is empty until you enter a search term. Not sure why it's not fully populating filteredImages and removing those that don't fit the query.

Comment: @Tholle This is my labels array. ["office", "technology", "passenger", "job"]. I'm still getting the filteredImages array only populating when I type in a search query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 class App extends Component {

      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          images:[],
          searchfield: '',
          filteredImages:[]
        }
      }

      getLabels = (image) => {
        const AuthKey = key.key;
        const res = axios.post(`https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=${AuthKey}`, {
          requests: [
            {
              image:{
                source:{
                  imageUri: `http://storage.googleapis.com/${image}`
                }
              },
              features:[
                {
                  type:"LABEL_DETECTION",
                  maxResults:10
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        });

        res.then(function (response) {
          const results = response.data.responses[0].labelAnnotations;
          const ex = results.map(result => {
            return result.description;
          }); 
          return ex;
        });

        return res;

      };

      componentDidMount() {
          imageFiles.imageFiles.forEach(img => {
            this.getLabels(img).then(result => {
              const results = result.data.responses[0].labelAnnotations;
              const labels = results.map(result => {
              return result.description;
            });
            //Add new values to the state 
            this.setState({images:[...this.state.images, {img, labels}]});
this.setState({filteredImages:[...this.state.images, {img, labels}]});
          });
        })
      }

      onSearchChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({searchfield: event.target.value});
        let filteredImages = this.state.images.filter(image => {
            return image.labels.includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase());
          });
        this.setState({filteredImages});
      }

      render() {

        // Create an array of objects to store the image path and the labels detected from Google Vision
        if (this.state.images.length === 0) {
          return <h1>Loading...</h1>
        } else {
          return (
            <Grid className="App">
              <SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
              <CardList images={this.state.filteredImages} />
            </Grid>
          )}
      }

    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm getting the same result though. I think the problem is that filteredImages is empty until you enter a search term. It should be fully populating the filteredImages array from this.state.images then filtering out those that don't match the query. Instead it looks like its starting empty and adding in the elements that match the query? Thanks for your time on this though, appreciate it.

Comment: in that case you need to call setState for filtered images in componentDidMount as well just after this.setState({images:[...this.state.images, {img, labels}]});
updates code with it.